# VBA copying data between sheets to irregular range

Tags: excel, vba

[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFN5x.png)

Hi All,

I know its abasic stuff but trying to learn VBA and encountered this issue while building my first macro. I have completely no idea how to pull this through.
I have a data set in sheet1 - an array of 9 columns with headers (the range is not definite and will vary month to month) out of which I need to populate the data into a form in sheet2. The problem is that the form is just built manually across spreadsheet2. Someone just drew a table and adapted it as a form and it cannot be changed (just some requirement) Another thing is that table was created in a way where some cells are one above the other so 2 rows would contain the data of one in the source. I placed the photos that should paint the picture of what Im trying to say. So the only thing I knew is how to copy one row of data but have no idea how to loop it so that each next row from spread sheet1 will populate itself accordingly among these two other rows. So the idea is for the macro to copy data from the source and create necessary number of these double rows until the source data runs out(dependantly on how bit source range will be as its dynamic) At the end there must be that summary of TOtal from last row.

Ive tried it like this

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet


ws1.Sheets("51").Range("H2").Copy
Sheets("Add 51").Range("A11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("51").Range("C2").Copy
Sheets("Add 51").Range("B11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("51").Range("E2").Copy
Sheets("Add 51").Range("D10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("51").Range("F2").Copy
Sheets("Add 51").Range("D11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("51").Range("D2").Copy
Sheets("Add 51").Range("E11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("51").Range("I2").Copy
Sheets("Add 51").Range("I11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you create, or do you have a primary key that can be used to fix where the data should go in Sheet2? If so, you could fix AAA as the key in both and then use an offset method to populate each value relative to Col A? That's one option.

Comment: You can just have two indexes: `Dim i, j: For i = 1 to 10: j = j + 2: Next i` Thats an example where `j` starts at 0 and ends at 20, `i` starts at 1 and goes to 10. Each worksheet can use its own index that all increment during the loop. They can all start at different rows, and increment in different step sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim rngDest As Range, rwSrc As Range, arr, i As Long
   
    Set rwSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("51").Range("C2:H2")          'first row of source data
    Set rngDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add 51").Range("A5:I6")    'destination for first row
    
    arr = Array("B2", "D2", "D1", "E1", "E2", "I2") 'array of *relative* addresses
    
    Do While Application.CountA(rwSrc) > 0 'while there's any data in the source row
        For i = 1 To rwSrc.Cells.Count     'loop over cells in source row
            'set value of a cell in `rngDest` using relative range address from `arr`
            rngDest.Range(arr(i - 1)).Value = rwSrc.Cells(i).Value 'i-1 because arr is zero-based
        Next i
        Set rwSrc = rwSrc.Offset(1)                      'next source row
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(rngDest.Rows.Count) 'next destination block
    Loop
End Sub
```

Relies on `Range()` being relative to the object it's called on, so for example

`Range("B2:C4").Range("A1")` is `B2`
`Range("B2:C4").Range("B2")` is `C3`

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you! It works like a charm. Still cannot figure how to delete remaining empty blocks in the destination form after the source data is filled. By default, it contains more these "blocks" than its possible there will be source data. But after the data is filled, I'd like them to be deleted. Cells not marked in yellow in these blocks are not empty and have some formulas that count based on the pasted data. Only last column "I" is always empty until the last row with grand total. Will appreciate the guidance

Comment: `rngDest.Parent.Range(rngDest.Row & ":499").Delete` for example if 500 is the row with the TOTAL.   If you don't know the last row then use `Find()` or `Match()` to locate the "TOTAL".

Comment: I came up with something like this but get constant error 
LR = Cells(rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
last = LR - 1
rngDest.Parent.Range(rngDest.Row & last).Delete

Comment: `rngDest.Parent.Range(rngDest.Row & ":" & last).Delete`